# How can I create a volume for the current user home directory in docker-compose?

Tags: docker-compose

For the docker image `v2tec/watchtower` I must provide the user-specific docker configuration file `config.json`. I am currently doing this as following:

```
version: "3"
services:
    watchtower:
    image: v2tec/watchtower
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - /home/thefrozenyoghurt/.docker/config.json:/config.json
```

This works on my machine. But I want to distribute this `docker-compose.yml` to my colleagues so they can use it also. This won't work with the `docker-compose.yml` above, as my home directory is hardcoded.

Is it possible to refer to the user home directory in a `docker-compose.yml`? I cannot find such functionalities in the documentation. I think I need something like:

```
version: "3"
services:
    watchtower:
    image: v2tec/watchtower
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - $HOME/.docker/config.json:/config.json
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`~/.docker/config.json` should work for this

```
version: "3"
services:
  watchtower:
    image: v2tec/watchtower
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
      - ~/.docker/config.json:/config.json
```

Comment: valid also for windows containers :D

Answer (score 32):

`~` wasn't working for us, it was creating folder called `something.json`, we fixed it like this:

```
volumes:
  - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  - ${HOME}/.docker/config.json:/config.json
```

Comment: maybe you can provide the version number?

Comment: it was version 2, now it works in version 3 as it is in main accepted answer

Comment: this is a linux/mac specific solution. Obviously there is also a windows specific solution as well. Is there any way that works for both windows/linux? I want to reference the users .ssh and .m2 folders in their home directory and distribute to a bunch of developers all using windows or mac. Annoying that I have to tell them "first manually edit the compose file if you are on mac ...)

Comment: sadly not working for me, `- /home/user/directory_name` is working,  `- ${HOME}/directory_name` not working. Maybe due to fact I have brand new docker and docker compose?

Answer (score 2):

For me `${HOME}/directory_name` it only worked after rebuilding the image