# How do I use plt.savefig() within docker container to save to my home directory

Tags: python, linux, docker, matplotlib, ubuntu

I am running docker on an Ubuntu server. Essentially I've created a container that produces plots using matplotlib, but I'm unsure how to get them to save to my home directory so that I can see the plots outside of the container. Can anyone possibly advise please?

Comment: You might run it in a Python virtual environment without Docker involved.  Ubuntu systems generally come with Python preinstalled and the virtual-environment tools are now part of the Python core.  This will let you run the application without requiring root-equivalent permissions and let you directly access your home directory without special options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) from your docker container to link a persisting storage unit.

You could then set this to be your home drive, [here is a question on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844377/how-can-i-create-a-volume-for-the-current-user-home-directory-in-docker-compose/47844971) (but it also uses more advanced docker concepts like compose)